# Yii isNewRecord is false in beforeSave?

Tags: php, yii

I made a beforeSave method in my model (extends GXActiveRecord), the if isNewRecord never gets triggered. My beforeSave() gets called, though.

When I print the  $this->isNewRecord variable, it's false. 
When is this variable set to false anyway?
I'm very sure it's new

```
public function beforeSave(){


        if(parent::beforeSave())
            {
              if($this->isNewRecord){
                    $this->setAttribute('doc_status','new');
                    print "something";
              }else{
                  $this->setAttribute('doc_status','updated');
              }
            return  true;
            }  else { return false;

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CActiveRecord->isNewRecord is false if you've never saved it before.

E.g.

```
$model = new Product;
$model->name = uniqid("bar");
echo "isNewRecord?".$model->isNewRecord; // 1 (true)
$model->save();
echo "isNewRecord?".$model->isNewRecord; // (false)

$model = Product::model();
$model->name = uniqid("foo");
echo "isNewRecord?".$model->isNewRecord; // (false)
$model->save();
echo "isNewRecord?".$model->isNewRecord; // (false)
```

Comment: In [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/10/how-to-automate-timestamps-in-activerecord-models/)  the example (second from last) points out that if isNewRecord then the created time stamp is updated, while if false then modified. From this I assumed that isNewRecord = true means it's new. Can you clarify ?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the return values, fixed that.
It works as you described.

Comment: Yes, but mine always says false before saving... I don't know why?!

Answer (score 5):

Well, this may be too late to answer, but I just wanted to get this out, cause this has caused enough confusion already (for me at least)...

If you call `parent::beforeSave()` in your model's beforeSave(), and test for `isNewRecord` after this, it will always evaluate to `false`, because model is saved.

You have your model built on top of a framework class, so when you override a method, do your task first then call on the parent method. So:

```
protected function beforeSave() {


if ($this->isNewRecord)
    //do something
else
    //do something else
/* some more code*/
parent::beforeSave();
return true;
}
```

You can also call parent beforeSave() like this:

```
return parent::beforeSave();
```

or

```
return true && parent::beforeSave();
```

Hope this helps other who find this question through google.

Answer (score 2):

At least in my case

```
print($this->isNewRecord);
print(parent::beforeSave());
print($this->isNewRecord);
```

prints `true` in every line.

And sorry I don't know how to reply to the answer above.